# How to control GPIO of another RPI

Tags: python, communication

I'm tring to build Home automation app, and I try to find ( unsuccessfully ) any code/ documentation for controling GPIO's of other RPI's, using Python.

Any leads ?

Comment: There is a remote GPIO option in raspi-config. Additional info is available here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=160310

Comment: @SteveRobillard- thank you very much, that is what i was looking 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) allows for the control of multiple Pi's GPIO from one or more Pis.

Your [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) program must import pigpio and create one or more instances of the pigpio.pi class. This class gives access to a specified Pi's GPIO.

Example

```py
pi1 = pigpio.pi()       # pi1 accesses the local Pi's GPIO
pi2 = pigpio.pi('tom')  # pi2 accesses tom's GPIO
pi3 = pigpio.pi('dick') # pi3 accesses dick's GPIO

pi1.write(4, 0) # set local Pi's GPIO 4 low
pi2.write(4, 1) # set tom's GPIO 4 to high
pi3.read(4)     # get level of dick's GPIO 4
```

Comment: is 'tom' and 'dick' RPI's hostnames ? can it be replaced with IP ?

Comment: Yes, 'tom' and 'dick' are host names and may be replaced by a dotted IP address, e.g. '192.168.1.24' (still need the quotes).

Comment: i get an error "ImportError: No module named 'gpiozero.pins.pigpio'"

what is needed to install this module ?

Comment: Try the command `man pigpio`.  If that works it means pigpio is installed.  If not, for Raspbian, use `sudo apt-get install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio`.  For other distributions use the instructions at http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong- but your answer and steve's are different, since yours uses pigpio module and steve's answer uses `from gpiozero.pins.pigpiod import PiGPIOPin` and need to run a daemon `pigpiod`. if so - what is the difference ?

Comment: gpiozero uses a GPIO library to implement the core GPIO functions.  gpiozero can use (I think) one of four different GPIO libraries.  To use remote GPIO it needs to use the pigpio GPIO library as pigpio is the only one to offer this functionality.

Comment: http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/api_pins.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Steve Robillard commented- the answer is found in:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=160310

or more specific answer( from his link )
http://bennuttall.com/whats-new-gpio-zero-v1-3/

Comment: gpiozero implements the remote host as a wrapper around pigpio.  gpiozero provides similar wrappers (without the remote host ability currently) around most of the Python GPIO libraries and offers an extensive suite of worked solutions.